# How to resize a mesh to perfectly fill a visionOS SwiftUI window using RealityKit

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

How can I create a mesh showing some text that perfectly fits a SwiftUI window? I am displaying the generated ModelEntity in a RealityView

```
 RealityView { content in
                var textEntity = modelFromText(title:reminder.title)
                content.add(textEntity)
            }
```

Generating the 3D ModelEntity dynamically using `MeshResource.generateText`

```
private func modelFromText(title:String) -> ModelEntity {
    let font:UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 0.7, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy, width: .condensed)
    let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText(
        title.localizedUppercase,
        extrusionDepth: 0.08,
        font: font,
        containerFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 20, height: 10),
        alignment: .left,
        lineBreakMode: .byWordWrapping
    )
    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: textMesh)
    let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .white, roughness: 1, isMetallic: true)
    entity.model?.materials = [material]
    entity.name = "title"
    enter code here
    return entity
}
```

I have trouble figuring out how the containerFrame definition works. As you can see the text always gets clipped in some way. I appreciate any advice.

[image: Clipped text mesh inside SwiftUI window on visionOS]

Answer (score 2):

RealityKit text is always offset to the right when created (text's pivot is located at lower left corner). And the text always goes beyond the window if the text size is large enough. Use `visualBounds(.)` method to calculate bounds of 3D text in a visionOS window. Then you can use its values to shift the text in the negative X direction. The text size should be small enough to fit the text in the window.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    private func modelFromText(_ title: String) -> ModelEntity {
        let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText(title,
                                        extrusionDepth: 0.015,
                                        font: .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 0.1))
        let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: textMesh)
        let material = UnlitMaterial(color: .systemOrange)
        entity.model?.materials = [material]
        return entity
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let text = modelFromText("Vision Pro")
            let offset = text.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents.x / 2
            text.position = [-offset, -0.05, -0.1]
            content.add(text)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]